# Multiplying Fractions Help

Tags: cross-product

How could I find each product or quotient for this problem? I got $$\frac{3q}{2r^2}$$ as an answer

The question is

$$\frac{(4r)^2}{q} \times  \frac{(3q)^2}{(8r)^4}$$ .

So is my answer correct ?

Comment: I suspect you're not right.  It's hard to say, though, because your formatting is a bit wonky.  Do you mean $\frac{(4r)^2}{q} \times \frac{(3q)^2}{(8r)^4}$?

Comment: If so, you must remember that in compound powers such as $(4r)^2$, $(3q)^2$, and $(8r)^4$, the constants are raised to the same power as the variables.  Thus, for instance, $(3q)^2 = (3q)(3q) = 9q^2$.  Does that change your answer?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(4r)^2}{q} \times \frac{(3q)^2}{(8r)^4} = \frac{16r^2}{q} \times \frac{9q^2}{4096r^4}$$

and so this will simplify to $$\frac{9q}{256r^2}$$